# Android Layout Manager Attributes

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

[Layout screen as an bug example[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5aOH.png)While developing my android app I deleted linear layout by selecting it in layout manager by mouse and pressing delete button after that android studio stopped giving me auto complete code suggestions in XML also layout manager is not showing all attributes associated with with a UI component Please guide me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml code might not be in proper format, like missing any closing bracket or something else, first you should check that.

Other steps to try:

- Build -> Clean Project -> Rebuild Project
- File -> Invalidate Caches and Resatart
- File ->Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings (it will reset your IDE, as if it is newly installed.)

Comment: Yes, I tried rebuilding my project and also invalidated caches and restarted.  It runs fine on mobile  layout manager is not working properly

Comment: Then try this `File ->Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings` it will reset your IDE, as if it is newly installed.

Comment: I uninstalled android studio and reinstalled it,  doing it solved the problem but this option  seems better way to do it thanks for guidance

Comment: @MoezAhmad Kindly upvote the answer , so that other needy can find it easily.